# Solve $y=\operatorname{erf}(x+c)+\operatorname{erf}(x-c)$ for $x$

Tags: special-functions, closed-form, error-function, optimal-transport

$\newcommand{\erf}{\operatorname{erf}}\newcommand{\erfc}{\operatorname{erfc}}$

Is there a closed form solution for $y=\erf(x+c)+\erf(x-c)$?
More specifically, I want to solve

$$\erf(\frac{y}{\sqrt{2}})=\frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\erf\bigl(\frac{x+μ}{\sqrt{2}σ}\bigr) +\erf\bigl(\frac{x-μ}{\sqrt{2}σ}\bigr)\Bigr)$$

Which came out of an optimal transport problem between Normal distributions.

**Notes:**

- Wolfram Cloud cannot solve it directly.
- Taking derivatives, one gets $y'(x)=e^{-(x+c)^2} + e^{-(x-c)^2}∝\cosh(2cx)e^{-x^2}$

Applying the series expansion $\erf(x)=\frac{2}{\sqrt{π}}\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}x^{2n+1}$ yields:

$$\begin{aligned}
y &=\frac{4}{\sqrt{π}}\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)} \biggl(\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2k}c^{2k}x^{2n+1-2k}\biggr)
\\&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{π}}\sum_{n=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)} \biggl(\sum_{j=0}^{n} \binom{2n+1}{2n-2j}c^{2n-2j}x^{2j+1}\biggr)
\\&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{π}}\sum_{j=0}^∞\biggl(\sum_{n=j}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2n+1)}\binom{2n+1}{2n-2j}c^{2n-2j}\biggr)x^{2j+1}
\\&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{π}}\sum_{j=0}^∞\biggl(\sum_{n=j}^∞ \frac{(-1)^n}{n!(2j+1)}\binom{2n}{2j}c^{2n-2j}\biggr)x^{2j+1}
\\&\text{Mathematica says the inner series simplifies to}
\\&=\frac{4}{\sqrt{π}}\sum_{j=0}^∞ \frac{(-1)^j {}_1F_1(j+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, -c^2)}{j!(2j+1)}x^{2j+1}
\\&\text{where ${}_1F_1$ is a hypergeometric function.}
\end{aligned}$$

The last term looks very similar to the series expansion of $\erf(x)$ itself, the $n$-th term gets multiplied by an additional factor $2⋅{}_1F_1(n+\frac{1}{2}, \frac{1}{2}, -c^2)$.

Any suggestions what else I could try? I am looking for a "closed-form" solutions, in terms of other special functions.

**EDIT:** User Тyma Gaidash٠ points to [Marcum-Q function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcum_Q-function) which satisfies

$$Q_{1/2}(x, μ) = \frac{1}{2}\Bigl(\erfc(\frac{x+μ}{\sqrt{2}}) + \erfc(\frac{x-μ}{\sqrt{2}})  \Bigr)$$

Hence, the problem is equivalent to computing an inverse of the Marcum-Q function. This is related to the [Noncentral chi-squared distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Noncentral_chi-squared_distribution); if I understand it correctly, the solution to my problem is given by the quantile function of a non-central χ² distribution.

Comment: Beside power series reversion, I do not see

Comment: I'd try expanding in $c$ (or $\mu$?)

Comment: @user619894. The problem is that the first term will be the error function itself.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici isn't the inverse erf a "special function"?

Comment: Given that I want to implement this, I am happy with any special function that `scipy` provides: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/special.html

Comment: Is $c$ big ? If not this could probably be approximated in defivatives of erf which are normal functions (e.g. https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1155676/399263)

Comment: @zwim That's a neat idea, we were considering small $c$ (<2), but it might be interesting to look into.

Comment: Likely this is a special case of “chndtr” and has a solution with a function like “chndtrix” or “chndtrinc” like [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/780747/approximating-the-erf-function/4392701#4392701) in scipy.